# Android Shared Preference check value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm working on android application that have 2 activities **A** and **B** . I have a button in `B Activity` with **event** that *save the current time* of android device, the time save in Shared Preferences:

```
long TimeMillis = date.getTime();
editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("TimeMillis", String.valueOf(TimeMillis));
```

I need to check the value of the previous Shared Preferences in `A Activity`

Note: the Date save on B then check it in A . A come before B.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your value from shared preferences anywhere you want like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String mSharedDate= prefs.getString("TimeMillis", "");
if(mSharedDate!=null){
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a value from SharedPreferences like this:

```
String time = sharedpreferences.getString("TimeMillis", "default_Value_Here");
```

"sharedpreferences" has to be an object of class SharedPreferences.
The second String ("default_Value_Here") should be something that gets set as String time when there is no key in sharedpreferences named "TimeMillis".

Another hint: You must call editor.commit() to save your changes in activity B.

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you can set a default value, in `getString()` method, which will be returned if you haven't set anything before.

You can set this value as you wish, then check it in order to understand if your value has been set.

```
final String NO_VALUE = "NO_VALUE";

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String mSharedDate = prefs.getString("TimeMillis", NO_VALUE);

if(mSharedDate.equals(NO_VALUE)){
    // No value handling
    return;
}

// do something
```